# Cannot understand why positive semi-definite matrices are interesting in machine learning

Tags: linear-algebra

Deep Learning book states the following fact 
[image]

and I cannot understand why they are interesting what what's so special about $x^{T} A x \geq 0$ and what are $x$ and $A$ in machine learning setting and what $x^{T} A x \geq 0$  implies.

Also why $x^{T} A x \geq 0$ on the first place?
For some reason got really confused...

Thank you

Comment: Not sure if these are the reasons you are looking for. 1) One can define a norm by $\|x\| = \sqrt{x^\top A x}$. This generalizes the Euclidean distance, and its contours are ellipses with axes given by the eigenvectors of $A$. 2) Many [optimization problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidefinite_programming) can be formulated using semidefinite matrices, and there has been much research in efficient algorithms to solve such problems.

Comment: Something is missing in those definitions; $$\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&3\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix}=-1,$$ but that matrix has positive eigenvalues. The last sentence is part of the [usual definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix), and the matrix is usually also required to be symmetric.

Comment: @angryavian euclidean norm is $\sqrt{x^Tx}$. What is A????

Comment: @YohanRoth I mean that $\sqrt{x^\top A x}$ (for a positive semidefinite $A$) defines a different norm. The Euclidean norm is the special case $A=I$.